# Is there any way to convert this equational String value into an int type value

Tags: java, string, integer

IS there any way to store this String value (or any other arithmatic equation) into an int variable ?

The equation is: `String eq1= "10*2+5/4";`

can eql be casted in `int i;`

i have tried explicit casting but it doesnt work.

Note that the equation `String eq1= "10*2+5/4";` is just for example , the user can enter any other numerical equation with arithmetic operators `+ , - , / , * and %`

I have to obtain the equation from JTextArea.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441625/how-to-find-a-button-source-in-awt-calculator-homework/7441804#7441804

Comment: You could use the integrated scripting engine to evaluate the formula and then use Integer.valueOf() to get the int value.

Comment: What happens if the expression is not valid arithmetic? Say, "/4*+5x".  Why do you need an int to represent the expression?  Define the characteristics of the int (range, meaning, etc.).